# check the values send by form in extjs

Tags: forms, extjs, submit, handler, sencha-architect

I use a fieldset in extjs and want to submit the values. For now i want to check the values with an alert but i dont see how i can do this.

```
{
   "xtype": "fieldset",
   "height": 377,
   "id": "configurationDriversConfiguration",
   "width": 648,
   "layout": {
      "type": "auto"
   },
   "collapsible": true,
   "title": "Driver Configuration",
   "items": [
      {
         "xtype": "button",
         "id": "configurationDriversAdd",
         "text": "Add"
      },
      {
         "xtype": "button",
         "id": "configurationDriversDelete",
         "text": "Delete"
      },
      {
         "xtype": "textfield",
         "id": "configurationDriversCode",
         "fieldLabel": "Driver Code"
      },
      {
         "xtype": "textfield",
         "id": "configurationDriversName",
         "fieldLabel": "Driver Name"
      },
      {
         "xtype": "textfield",
         "id": "configurationDriversLicense",
         "fieldLabel": "Driver License nr"
      },
      {
         "xtype": "textfield",
         "id": "configurationDriversGivenName",
         "fieldLabel": "Driver Given Name"
      },
      {
         "xtype": "textfield",
         "id": "configurationDriversFamilyName",
         "fieldLabel": "Driver Familiy Name"
      },
      {
         "xtype": "textfield",
         "id": "configurationDriversPhone",
         "fieldLabel": "Driver Phone Nr"
      },
      {
         "xtype": "textfield",
         "id": "configurationDriversEmail",
         "fieldLabel": "Driver Email"
      },
      {
         "xtype": "combobox",
         "id": "configurationDriversProvider",
         "fieldLabel": "Provider",
         "displayField": "name",
         "store": "comboProviders",
         "valueField": "id"
      },
      {
         "xtype": "textareafield",
         "id": "configurationDriversMemo",
         "fieldLabel": "Memo"
      },
      {
         "xtype": "button",
         "height": 37,
         "id": "configurationDriversSave",
         "text": "Save"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is my code. When i click on save i want to see all the values. I use Sencha Architect and can't find the handler for this

Comment: What exactly do you need? Check values for what? Are you looking for some kind of validation?

Comment: a validation would be nice. But what i need is that when i press on save it does something :) And to see what it does i would like to see the submitted values. For example what was filled in at configurationDriversName

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to the 'Save' button definition:

```
handler: function(btn) {
   var fieldSet = btn.up('fieldset');
   Ext.Array.each(fieldset.items, function(i) {
       console.log(i.getValue());
   });
}
```

Comment: i do this: handler: function(button, event) {
                                                                var fieldSet = button.up('configurationDriversConfiguration');
                                                                Ext.Array.each(fieldSet.items, function(i) {
                                                                    alert(i.getValue());
                                                                });

                                                            }
But i get a fieldSet is undefined
Ext.Array.each(fieldSet.items, function(i) {
error

Comment: I think if you need to look up by id you need to specify #my_id in selector. Without anything - it would be xtype

Comment: Come on man... Try to read some documentation on how to go through array of items. I stated my code is not perfect sample - but a direction to go.